# Difference between "Linear detrending" and "Linear decorrelation" in spectral analysis

Tags: linear-regression

I am looking for an example that explains (with a plot if possible) the difference between (if there is one)  "linear detrending" v "linear decorrelation of stellar activity tracers".

Also if there is a difference, is there python code that deals with one or the other?

Thanks

General question here, no code.